# when clicked on any list view item, show that item text into EditText

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I'm getting values for ListItem from String array and showing them as ListView, also I had added EditText field so that when user enters some text then listview shows only matching items. My concern is that when User click on any listview item the text from this item must be shown inside edittext field, I had tried so many methods like, onitemclicklistener, viewgroup but hadn't get succeded, each time getting errors. Below is my code and please help me with this.
MainActivity.java

```
private ListView lv;
    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;
    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Listview Data
        final String products[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Countreis);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                if(cs.length()== 0){
                    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search products.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
    <!-- List View -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- Single ListItem -->
 <!-- Product Name -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>   
 </LinearLayout>
```

String Array:

```
    <string-array name="Countreis">
        <item >India</item>
        <item >Pakistan</item>
        <item >Bnagladesh</item>
        <item >Nepal</item>
        <item >China</item>
        <item >Russia</item>
        <item >America</item>
        <item >Ingland</item>
        <item >Japan</item>
        <item >Arab emirat</item>
        <item >Saudi Arabia</item>
        <item >Austrelia</item>
        <item> Kuwiat</item>
        <item >Israil</item>
   </string-array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        inputSearch.setText((String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(position));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement ListView item click listener :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         inputSearch.setText(adapter.getItem(position));
    }
});
```

Comment: It is setting text into edittext field but it is showing different result then clicked item, mean suppose I enter "a" into edittext field  then it shows 4 results based on a, when I click any result it displays item matching to array, not as on real result.